# How to merge sorted files without using a temporary file?

Tags: unix, sorting, command-line, temporary-files

I'm trying to merge many sorted files in a UNIX/Linux script with `sort -m`, and I noticed that `sort` first writes the result to a temporary file, then copies it to destination. My understanding of `-m` was that it assumes the files are sorted, so using a temporary file is completely unnecessary, and it wastes both hard disk space and CPU cycles (I'm using `sort` in a pipeline which gets stuck waiting for sort to output anything.) Is there a way to tell `sort` to not use temporary files when merging sorted files? Or a better version which doesn't?

The exact CL looks like:

```
$ sort -m -s -t '_' -k 1,1n -k 2,2n <(gunzip <file_1) [...] <(gunzip <file_n) | gzip >output
```

I'm using `sort` from GNU coreutils 5.97.

Comment: I think because `sort` was written as a general purpose utility, they didn't consider your case as something to add more complexity to the program and so rely on the std sort mechanism of tmp files. .... It would be pretty easy to write an awk script that cycles thru your list of input files, compares each 1st line, prints the 'lowest' value from one file, get the next record from that file, then compares all the records again, looking to print the next 'lowest' record. You might run into a system limit on open file, but this would be true of any solution you code. test 4 that first. Good Luck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out these options from `man sort`, they might let you minimize the amount of space needed for merging.

```
--batch-size=NMERGE
```

merge at most NMERGE inputs at once; for more use temp files

```
--compress-program=PROG
```

compress temporaries with PROG; decompress them with PROG -d

Comment: This is not a solution to the question, since it was asked how to prevent temporary files, and why temporary files are needed?
Your answer help in reducing temporary files, but doesn't prevent them. For big files, it still uses temp files

Comment: It does solve the problem. You have to set the `--batch-size` higher than the number of files you want to merge. I had 31 files to merge and without specifying that option it started using a temp file. When setting `--batch-size=31`, it started writing the output right away without a temp file.

Comment: i successfully used --batch-size=520 to merge that many large sorted files; without the option it was extremely slow

Comment: On MS Windows I had only access to a non-GNU unix like sort.exe. I could speed my sorting up by finding out when sort -m was using temp files (this was with 6 or more files) then implement script that took 5 files from the list (a merge without temp files), merge them and put the result file back onto the end of list and continue till I've one file left. That reduced lead time also with many hours. (Had to merge 4000 files with total size of 6GB).

Answer (score 1):

Running with GNU coreutils 6.10, I'm not seeing that problem.

One thing about the command line that you're using is that the <(...) redirection writes the input to a temporary file before starting the command.  Could that be the delay you are seeing?

I ran this command:

```
sort -m a b c d e f g h i j | more
```

and it did not create a temp file for the output.  I piped the output into more so it would block and then looked in /proc to see what sort was doing.  It had all of the input files opened, and the pipe to the more command, but that was it.  No temporary file:

```
$ ls -l /proc/1308/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 0 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 1 -> pipe:[217016034]
lr-x------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 10 -> /home/brianb/h
lr-x------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 11 -> /home/brianb/i
lr-x------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 12 -> /home/brianb/j
lrwx------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 3 -> /home/brianb/a
lr-x------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 4 -> /home/brianb/b
lr-x------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 5 -> /home/brianb/c
lr-x------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 6 -> /home/brianb/d
lr-x------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 7 -> /home/brianb/e
lr-x------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 8 -> /home/brianb/f
lr-x------ 1 brianb brianb 64 2014-06-24 18:50 9 -> /home/brianb/g
```